# How to resolve 404 url not found on amazon aws ,symfony 4 project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment, symfony4, php-7

I have deployed my symfony 4 website on amazon aws. When i am trying to access homepage of the deployed 
 website i can access it but when i am trying to access other routes/webpages like /contactus . I am getting this error :

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I have setup test enviroment in .env file of the symfony 4 project

How can resolve this issue ?